# How can I use vendor-packaged modules from a Perl I compiled myself?

Tags: perl, perl-module

My OS-Distribution provides the rpm-package "perl-obexftp", which installs the Modul "OBEXFTP". 
These are the files:

> /usr/lib/perl5/vendor_perl/5.10.0/x86_64-linux-thread-multi/OBEXFTP.pm
>   /usr/lib/perl5/vendor_perl/5.10.0/x86_64-linux-thread-multi/auto/OBEXFTP
>   /usr/lib/perl5/vendor_perl/5.10.0/x86_64-linux-thread-multi/auto/OBEXFTP/.packlist
>   /usr/lib/perl5/vendor_perl/5.10.0/x86_64-linux-thread-multi/auto/OBEXFTP/OBEXFTP.bs
>   /usr/lib/perl5/vendor_perl/5.10.0/x86_64-linux-thread-multi/auto/OBEXFTP/OBEXFTP.so
>   /var/adm/perl-modules/obexftp

I am using now a Perl which I have build from the source.
Is there a simple way to make this OBEXFTP-module accesseble to my Perlinstallation?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Choose one of

- Add the following pragma to your code:

  ```
  use lib '/usr/lib/perl5/vendor_perl/5.10.0';
  ```
- Add that path to the `PERL5LIB` environment variable
- Invoke your code with `perl -I/usr/lib/perl5/vendor_perl/5.10.0 program`
- Rebuild perl so that path is in its baked-in `@INC`
- Build the module yourself using your custom-built perl

For details, see [perlrun](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlrun.html).

Comment: I was on the right way - I copied the files to "/usr/local/lib/perl5/site_perl/5.10.1/x86_64-linux" respectively to "/usr/local/lib/perl5/site_perl/5.10.1/x86_64-linux/auto/OBEXFTP".
Since with the "use lib '/usr/lib/perl5/vendor_perl/5.10.0';"-method I get the same error-message (Bus-Zugriffsfehler; in English maybe something like "bus-access-error") there might be something wrong elsewhere.